# How to easily forward from a jsp to several actions

Tags: struts2, struts

I am quite a newbie on struts, and here is my problem :

I have a jsp which is accessed from several actions. On this jsp, i have a 'Back' button which has to forward the user to the previous page. The previous page must be called with the originally parameters.
What are the solutions to achieve this ?

I tried to pass a parameter to the jsp to tell which action to call when the user clicks the 'back' button (ie i call my page in such a way : /myJsp?back=loadMyPage.do) : and in the jsp the 'back' button uses this 'back' parameter to redirect the user to the adequate action.

I think it can be a good solution when only one (or a few) pages are using this mechanism, but it gets complicated when several pages are each used by several actions : we d have to pass the 'back' parameter to each page.

So i m wondering how to achieve this easily. I m also asking myself if it has sense to do that forwarding work inside a jsp : is it better to do all work in actions classes ?

I hope i was clear

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason that using the browser's back button doesn't work well enough? If you really need your own button, can it not just call `history.back()`?

Comment: i can't use history.back() because the actual code intensively uses requests parameters (request scope)